# How to calculate the growth rate, and time amount of an algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, time, complexity-theory

I am currently enjoying *Think Complexity* by Allen Downey and a few hours ago I finished the section on growth rate. I paused reading and googled growth rates, and expanded on the info the book gave me. I also found out that you can calculate the amount of *time* it takes for an algorithm to calculate the raw data. I have a lot of questions that can't be answered by google, or maybe I need a personal touch in my answers since it really helps me understand. My questions are:

**1-** How is it possible to calculate the growth rate of a simple algorithm? For example, I just wrote this loop to calculate sine of a given angle in radians using Tayler series:

```
    for i in range(0, 360):
        return sum(((-1)**i / (factorial((2 * i) + 1))) * d ** ((2*i) + 1))
```

And factorial:

```
def factorial(n):
    factorial = 1
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        factorial *= i

return factorial
```

How do I calculate its growth rate?

**2-** I became familiar with some very bad algorithms like Bogosort. It takes a large amount of time to sort an array using bogosort. But how do you calculate the time? It differs from computer to computer.

**3-** What is the Big-O notation and how is it related to the growth rate?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Generally it is not a good approach to calculate the time a function takes since it is dependent on many factors. For this reason we often express complexity in terms of computational steps. E.g. big O notation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: Question (1) Depends on how factorial is implemented; an implementation that  caches previous results would be much different than one that doesn't.

Comment: @HyperZ: Understood. I'm going for another source other than Wikipedia though. It burns my brain, I'm not very smart.

Comment: @DanHydar: I added the factorial. So what is it? Logarithmic? Linear? Square?

Comment: @CodesInTheValley Looking at the definition of `factorial` we notice that the for loop runs once from 0 to n+1. Hence it is linear with the input. Hence, O(n).

Comment: @HyperZ: Thank you. I'm close to getting my answer. So the big-O notation is O(n). What does that entail?

Comment: @CodesInTheValley O(n) means that `n` is an upper bound. Hence, this means that in the worst case `factorial` will do n steps. In fact, in your case you can be sure that it will do exactly n steps, hence it is better to say that factorial is Ө(n) (big theta).

Comment: @HyperZ: I can't upvote you so thanks.

Comment: @CodesInTheValley I grouped my comments in an answer, such that it can be useful for future readers of this question. :)

Comment: Sorry. I did. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally it is not a good approach to calculate the time a function takes since it is dependent on many factors. For this reason we often express complexity in terms of computational steps.

Multiple notations exist (big-Oh, big-Omega, big-Theta).
Big-Oh represents an upper bound, hence O(n) indicates that in the worst-case it will perform n steps.

Big-Omega (Ω) is a lower bound, hence Ω(n) indicates a minimum of n steps.
A combination of both is big-theta Ө, hence, Ө(n) indicates that it will take exactly n steps.

In your case, `factorial` is defined as

```
def factorial(n):
    factorial = 1
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        factorial *= i

return factorial
```

This function will loop once from 1 to n+1, hence, it depends on its argument n. We can say that it will perform exactly n steps, hence, we can say that `factorial` is in Ө(n). Note that this is clearly linear.